# Consulting previous index in a Python for loop

Tags: python

I have a script that searches a txt for a keyword (ex: APPLE) and if **true**, it changes another part (ex: "00" or "01" or "02") to **"22"** of that same TXT in same line, to exemplify, I will follow with these three lines:

INPUT:
123456 BANANA 00 SP
123457 APPLE  01 RJ
123458 PEAR  02 MG

*script run*

OUTPUT:
123456 BANANA 00 SP
123457 APPLE **22** RJ
123458 PEAR 02 MG

That these three lines are part of the same "header".

The code that is already doing that (the number of positions does not reflect reality, it is just an example, but in the actual file they have a layout with positions fixed):

```
import shutil, tempfile

# reads from file and writes to another temporary file
with open ('teste.txt', 'r') as file, \
     tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile ('w', delete = False) as out:
    for line in file:
        code = line [07:14] # APPLE SEARCH
        
        if code == 'APPLE':
           print ("FOUND, CODE:" + code)
           line = line [: 14] + "22" + line [16:] # reassemble the line with the change
        else:
           print ("NOT FOUND, CODE:" + code)

        out.write (line) # write to temporary file

# move the temporary file to the original
shutil.move (out.name, 'test.txt')
```

However, there is a logic problem in this solution, because my reality is that if on the **second line** I find the "APPLE", I will not change the same line, but in the top line, which belongs to "BANANA" and that my code has passed. So the result I expect if the script ends is:

123456 BANANA **22** SP
123457 APPLE 01 RJ
123458 PEAR 02 MG

The solution I think of: create a list called **"exit"** and increase it, so when I need to retrieve one position, I just do a **[exit - 1]**, but isn't working... into the file are saving just the lines that has changed, and that it's because I'm overwriting my current "line" with my previously line, but I don't know how to proceed with this. Here is my solution that is not working:

```
import shutil, tempfile

# reads from file and writes to another temporary file
exit = []
with open ('teste.txt', 'r') as file, \
     tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile ('w', delete = False) as out:
    
    for i, line in enumerate (file):
        code = line [07:14]
        
        if code == 'APPLE':
           print ("FOUND, CODE:" + code)
           line = exit [i - 1]
           line = line [: 14] + "22" + line [16:] # reassemble the line
           
        else:
           print ("NOT FOUND, CODE:" + code)
           
        out.write (line) # write to temporary file
        exit.append (line)
        
# move the temporary file to the original
shutil.move (out.name, 'test.txt')
```

Finally, my question is: how do I "return" a position in the index BEFORE reassembling the line in a python for?

**UPDATE**

I followed some advices and create a list with all my lines, so I can back when necessary, so I did it:

```
import shutil, tempfile

outLines = []
# reads from file and writes to another temporary file
with open ('teste.txt', 'r') as file, \
     tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile ('w', delete = False) as out:
        for i, line in enumerate (file):
            exit.append (line)
            code = line [14:23]
            if code == 'APPLE':
               print ("FOUND, CODE:" + code)
               outLines [i] = outLines [i-1] [:14] + "22" + outLines [i-1] [16:] # reassemble the line
               lineout = outLines [i]
               out.write (lineout)
            else:
               print ("NOT FOUND, CODE:" + code)
               
            out.write (line) # write to temporary file
# move the temporary file to the original
shutil.move (out.name, 'test.txt')
```

The problem now is that my code is repeating the first line, for exmpl, my output now it's some like that:

123456 BANANA 01 SP
123456 BANANA **22** SP
123457 APPLE 01 RJ
123458 PEAR 02 MG

How to proceed without repeating the first line? I imagine it’s because I’m recording “line” later and they’re considering the line unchanged ...

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you write each line as you encounter it.  When you find `APPLE`, you have already written the `BANANA` line to the output file.

The most straightforward change to your code is to save all of your lines in `exit` until you have read the entire input file.  When you find `APPLE`, alter the previous element of `exit` (note that your present code fails to do this).  When you reach the end of the input file, *then* write the output file from `exit`.

NOTE: you should change the variable name `exit`, since that is the name of a built-in function.

Can you handle the logic from here?

Comment: I did an update in my post... could you help me to finish?

Comment: I already did: you did not use my suggestion of "most straightforward change".